# How to serialize java.sql.Date as Long, when using web services?

Tags: glassfish, jaxb, service, glassfish-3

I have a simple web service method that returns a simple java class as return value.

```
@WebMethod()
public SimpleClass myMethod();

@XmlRootElement()
public class SimpleClass {
    @XmlElement(name="myDate")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyDateAdapter.class)
    public java.sql.Date myDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
}
```

I want that java.sql.Date will transmitted as Long value in the XML (because the client is J2ME that cannot handle complex things).
For this puprpose I took the solution that was mentioned in many places before, and worked great on Glassfish v2.

First, I declare the following adapter:

```
 public class MyDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Long, java.sql.Date> {
     public java.sql.Date unmarshal(Long v) throws Exception {
        return new java.sql.Date(v);
     }
     public Long marshal(java.sql.Date v) throws Exception {
         return v.getTime();
     }
 }
```

Then, I declare its usage in package-info file like this:

```
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyDateAdapter.class,type=java.sql.Date.class)
 })
 package mingler.tracker.ejb.client;
```

The problem happens on GlassFish 3. The date is transmitted as "xs:dateTime" value, instead of Long, although I defined the adapter properly.
This is the response I get from GlassFish 3 server, when I call my web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <S:Body>
         <ns2:myMethodResponse xmlns:ns2="http://nevermind.com">
             <return>
                 <myDate xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2010-12-09T12:44:06.875+02:00</myDate>
             </return>
         </ns2:myMethodResponse>
     </S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
```

I also checked with the debugger -- the functions in the adapter are never called.
On the other hand, the adapater is not useless, because if I try to remove it I get JAXB exception,
telling me that java.sql.Date cannot be handled because it doesn't have no-arg constructor.

Any ideas?

20/12/2010 -
I added links to a project jar with sources and the results for glassfish2 and glassfish3:
[jar file](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0ByO3mn9sWqFQODllZWFmNTktNzIxZi00NjcyLTkyMGItYjgxMmRmM2U0ZjNj&hl=en&authkey=CLW5hcYL) ,[glassfish3 result](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0ByO3mn9sWqFQMGJkY2FlMzYtY2Q1MC00OGIyLThlYTQtNGJiMTkzZjU4MGEy&hl=en&authkey=CPqKgbYI) , [glassfish2 result](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0ByO3mn9sWqFQNGI0OWQ2YTEtOWI0Mi00Y2Q0LWJmNTctMDI2MGUzMDZkMzhj&hl=en&authkey=CO2B8LcF)

Comment: Are you saying this same code deploys and works as expected on GF v2?

Comment: Yes, I added a project jar and detailed results for running on GFv2&3. It works as expected on GFv2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted a bug for this issue, it should be solved on version 3.1 ([link](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15439))

Answer (score 1):

You have the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter declared at both the property level and the package level.  Have you tried only declaring it in one spot?

Either:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyDateAdapter.class)
public java.sql.Date myDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

Or:

```
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyDateAdapter.class,type=java.sql.Date.class)
 })
 package mingler.tracker.ejb.client;
```

Instead of both.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer,

I did try declare it only in one place, either in package level or at property level, but still – no luck. It doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest enter a bug for this issue.  This can be done here:  http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS